# A Question on which solution is false and where (with logarithms)

Tags: inequality, logarithms

This question was put to me yesterday during a meeting with one of my highschool school teacher who taught me mathematics.

The question:

Find the domain of the function $f:x \to$ $log_\frac{1}{10}  \frac{2x+1}{x+2}$.From this, solve the inequality $f(x) \ge log_\frac{1}{10}  \frac{1}{x}$.

Solution for the domain of the function:

Since $ \frac{2x+1}{x+2} = \frac{2x+4-3}{x+2}$ = 2- $\frac{3}{x+2} \ge 0$,then $x \in $$(-\infty,-2) \cup (-\frac{1}{2},\infty):=S$

Here comes the funny part, my teacher offered two solutions for solving the inequality:

solution 1 (which is also similar to mine) :

With the premise of $x \in S = D_f$, we have that

$log_\frac{1}{10}  \frac{2x+1}{x+2} \ge log_\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{x}$

$\iff$ $\frac{2x+1}{x+2} \le \frac{1}{x}$ $\land$ $\frac{1}{x} \gt 0$

$\iff$ $\frac{2(x+1)(x-1)}{x(x+2)} \le 0$ $\land$ $x \gt 0$

$\iff$ $x-1 \le 0 \land x \gt 0$

$\iff$ $x \le 1 \land x \gt 0$

Hence $x \in (0,1]$

Solution 2(which I personally think that there's something wrong with this solution) :

Consider $f(x) \ge log_\frac{1}{10}  \frac{1}{x}$

Choose y such that $f(y) = log_\frac{1}{10}  \frac{1}{x}$ $\land$ $x \gt 0$

so

$\begin{cases} f(x) \ge f(y)\\log_\frac{1}{10} (2-\frac{3}{y+2})=log_\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{x}\\ x \gt 0 \land y\in S\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} x \le y  ,&\text{(because $f$ is decreasing)} \\ 2-\frac{3}{y+2}=\frac{1}{x} ,&\text{(take the $antilog={0.1}^{x}$ of both sides)} \\ x \gt 0 \land y\in S\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} x+2\le y+2\\ y+2 =\frac{3x}{2x-1}\\ x \gt 0 \land y\in S\end{cases}$

sub the second equation to the first inequality and we will get

$x+2 \le \frac{3x}{2x-1} \land x,2x-1 \gt 0$

$(x+2)(2x-1)-3x \le 0 \land x\gt \frac{1}{2} $

$2(x-1)(x+1) \lt 0  \land x\gt \frac{1}{2} $

$(x-1)\lt 0  \land x\gt \frac{1}{2} $

Hence $ \frac{1}{2} \lt x \le 1 $

Which solution is wrong and where?

Comment: Misprint at the beginning of solution 2: you typed $f(x)\le f(y)$ instead of $f(x)\ge f(y)$ (+ you could improve the look by replacing everywhere $log$ by $\log$).

Comment: ohh,my bad ,thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution is wrong because $f$ is only decreasing on each of the two intervals $(-\infty,-2)$ and $(-\frac12,\infty)$ but not on their union.

So, a large forgotten part of the solution is when $y<-2$ (and $x>0$, and $y=\frac{2-x}{2x-1}$), i.e. $0<x<\frac12.$

Moreover, the value $x=\frac12$ is also forgotten because there is no $y$ such that $\frac{2y+1}{y+2}=2.$

Comment: thanks, that clears a lot